# Merge two dataframes, if multiple columns are identical

Tags: python, pandas, merge

So I searched a bit here, but I couldn't find what I was looking for exactly...

Apologies, if i'm missing something here.

I will use an example to show what I want to accomplish suppose I have the following DFs:

```
    df1= p1        p2        p3   ...      p13       Data#
        0.000      0.000     0.0005429    0.001539
        0.0243     0.03459    0.00000      0.000019 
        ...  
       0.0045     0.000       0.000135      0.2145
```

and df2

```
   df2= p1        p2        p3   ...      p13          Prospect #
       0.0243     0.03459    0.00000      0.000019
       0.0045     0.000       0.000135      0.2145
       0.000      0.000     0.0005429    0.001539
```

DF1 has every entry of df2, and far more (700k more), however I want to merge these dataframes when EVERY value, p1-p13 is correct, and have my resulting frame contain the rows from both.

I attempted to use the following code:

```
 m1 = pd.read_csv(r'df1.csv') #my file with 62k which maps to 1 row in master
 m2 = pd.read_csv(r'df2.csv')#mymasterfile
 m3 = pd.merge(m1, m2, how ='outter', on= ['p1','p2','p3','p4','p5','p6','p7','p8','p9','p10','p11','p12','p13'])
```

This results in me getting multiple values mapped to a single entry in the master data frame.

[image]

I feel like I am missing a very obvious step here, but have been at it for a while now and can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be grealty appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by values being correct?

Comment: @Victor , are you saying `merge the dataframe on the identical columns` ?

Comment: if the above being said is True then try `df1.update(df2, raise_conflict=True)`  or  `df1.combine_first(df2)`

Comment: you do realize that 'outter' should be 'outer' in your code?

Comment: @zanshin yes that was just a typo